# Using mysql2 npm package on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, mysql2

Using this code to connect, works locally. I can even connect from my local machine to the Cloud SQL database.

```js
 options = {
        host: 'cloud.sql.ip',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'password12345',
        database: 'dbname',
        waitForConnections: true,
        connectionLimit: 10,
        queueLimit: 0
    };
    
 const pool = require('mysql2/promise').createPool(options);
```

When deploying I get this error: `rror: connect ETIMEDOUT at PoolConnection.Connection._handleTimeoutError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:192:13) at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11) at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5) at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)`

App.yaml looks like this:

```js
runtime: nodejs8
service: servicename

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: project-id:us-central1:instance-id
```

Comment: May I ask you to test first with the `mysql` package, as used in this [quickstart](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/cloudsql), to see if you can connect when deploying? To discard any problems with your Cloud SQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

the `beta_settings cloud_sql_instances` setting is used for App Engine flexible environment.

On the App Engine standard environment, you have direct socket access to CloudSQL by using the following socketPath: `/cloudsql/[YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]`